# How to edit "item-inner" class in item-native div in ionic v4?

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have to remove the extra padding being adding up in .item-inner class inside .item-native.
https://ibb.co/vs4BWWp

```
<div class="item-native">
<slot name="start">
</slot>
<div class="item-inner">
<div class="input-wrapper">
<slot></slot>
</div><slot name="end"></slot>
<div class="item-inner-highlight"></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you share `css`?

Comment: @rchau for? can u please describe it more?

Comment: share the style of `item-inner`. Also, is the `item-native` dynamic?

Answer (score 45):

```
ion-item{
    --inner-padding-end: 0px;
    --padding-start:0px
}
```

This works, because since ionic 4 web components & shadow DOM were introduced to keep "essential CSS" isolated.

In a lot of cases it just works to put -- in front of the wanted CSS attribute to change it or in other words: just define a CSS variable with the same name as the attribute you want to change.

Does someone know a complete reference to ionic's shadow DOM or something like that?

Further information:
[Shadow DOM in Ionic (and Why it’s Awesome)](https://ionicframework.com/blog/shadow-dom-in-ionic-and-why-its-awesome/), [CSS Shadow Parts](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-shadow-parts),
[CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*), [Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components)

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks very much I will take not when posting

Comment: Wow. I tried several answer but this one is working well.

Comment: Works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

`.item-native .item-inner{padding:0}`. this will remove padding of that element

Answer (score 0):

this and remove padding of that element with class item-inner:

```
.item-inner{
 padding:0 !important;
}
```

Comment: try <div class="item-inner" style="padding:0; margin:0"> but this not gut awy

Comment: please see ionic once it is run time created div with item inner having in it. so cannot use html css.